# Difference between lazy{} vs getter() initialization in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, getter-setter, lazy-initialization

In kotlin we can use both of these approach `lazy{}` and `getter()`

**lazy initializaiton:**

```
internal val connector by lazy {
        serviceConnector
    }
```

**getter():**

```
internal val connector : ServiceConnector
        get() = serviceConnector
```

When to use which approach and what actually does these two approach under the hood. Which one is best approach?

Answer (score 9):

When you use the `lazy` delegate, the `val` is initialized only when you use it the first time. So, in your code, the first time you access `connector`, the code inside the lambda is run, and the result is assigned to the `val`.

`get()`, instead, is used to redefine what happens when you try to access the `val`.

Comment: If, I am changing the serviceconnector?

Comment: I edited my answer, because the second part was wrong. When you change `serviceConnector`, you are also changing what is returned by get(), since each time you access `connector` you run the code in `get()`. With `lazy` instead, the val is assigned at the time of first usage, then doesn't change anymore.

Comment: Can we use lazy and get at the same time, I couldn't figure out how to use `get` to modify the behaviour of `getter` calls with `by lazy` on the same variable, Thanks